# Parameter in route handler in Kohana 3.0 returns empty value

Tags: php, routes, kohana-3, bootstrapping

I'm currently in the process of writing a custom routeHandler in Kohana 3.0. Basically a large portion of my site is related to specific items, so rather than have a load of controllers then actions then id's appearing in the URL I'd rather just have the name. Which of course means I need to manipulate the routes.

My bootstrap contains the following:

```
Route::set('routeHandler', '(<url>)',
    array(
        'url' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_/-]+',
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
            'controller' => 'routeHandler',
            'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

This redirects me to my routesHandler controller.

Inside the controller I then set some more routes and eventually make a new request.
However, when it comes to getting the uri to pass it appears empty.

```
 $this->request->param('uri'); // Comes back empty?
```

When I print out the request I get the following info:

```
Request Object 
( 
   [route] => Route Object 
       ( 
           [_uri:protected] => () 
           [_regex:protected] => Array 
               ( 
                   [url] => [a-zA-Z0-9_/-]+ 
               ) 
           [_defaults:protected] => Array 
               ( 
                   [controller] => routeHandler 
                   [action] => index  
               ) 
           [_route_regex:protected] => #^(?:(?P[a-zA-Z0-9_/-]+))?$#uD 
        ) 
   [status] => 200 
   [response] => 
   [headers] => Array 
       ( 
           [Content-Type] => text/html; charset=utf-8 
       ) 
   [directory] => 
   [controller] => routeHandler 
   [action] => index 
   [uri] => 
   [_params:protected] => Array 
       ( 
       ) 
)
```

Is there something I have missed in my bootstrap?
I've also noticed a loss of certain variables set in the bootstrap such as `base_url`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the parameter mentioned in your route is `url` and not `uri`, try:

```
$this->request->param('url');
```